# What does "日本語だと聞く立場になって" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've just come across this sentence:

> 初めて会った人と何を話したらいいかわからない時や、中心になって話したいけど、日本語だと聞く立場になってしまうときはありませんか。

I'm fine with other parts, but what does "日本語だと聞く立場になってしまうとき" mean?

Comment: Translation requests are off-topic here. Please show your own translation attempt, or this thread would probably get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> （Ａ）初めて会った人と何を話したらいいかわからない時や、中心になって話したいけど、日本語だと聞く立場になってしまうときはありませんか。

（Ａ）は、あまり良い日本語とは思えません。
（Ａ）を、例｛たと｝えば（Ｂ）のように書き換｛か｝えると分かり易｛やす｝いと思います。

> （Ｂ）「初めて会った人と何を話したらいいかわからない時や、（自分が話題提供の）中心になって話したい時に、**日本語で話すべき内容を考えていると / 日本語での会話だと**、いつの間にか、自分が他人の話を聞く立場になってしまう」、そのようなときはありませんか。

Comment: どうもありがとうございました。
最初そうとも思っていましたが、あまり自信がありませんでした。

ところで、これはテキストにある文です。

Comment: @マイナスの投票をした人へ　どこがマイナスであるかコメントするか、ご自身の回答を提示してください。それが質問者への礼儀です。

Comment: （別にDVするほどではないですけど）「～な時や～な時はありませんか？」という、主語が2つ並列されている文ですので、そのカギ括弧の囲み方にはかなり違和感があります。